# Pointer as a class variable Qt

Tags: c++, qt

When you just creating Qt application, its automatically create main window for you, and i understood pretty everything except last thing in private: scope

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Can anybody explain what kind of pointer is that `Ui::MainWindow *ui;` and what purpose of it? As i understand it is an empty pointer "for future" type of which is class MainWindow, so it means that this member is an object inside it's own class, am i correct?

P.S. and what was the need to create that namespace Ui?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the pointer to the auto-generated class (based on the .ui file created by the Qt Designer or more precisely - uic.exe). You need it to access widgets that you place on your form in the designer (since you don't create them manually in the code).

Other than that, it's nothing special. Just a pointer to some forward-declared class (which in your case would be defined in the ui_MainWindow.h). It has it's own namespace to not clash with your classes.

Comment: So i assume that i can remove that useless namespace which created by Qt?

Comment: You shouldn't remove the namespace, then the MainWindow.cpp will not compile (since your compiler does not know that class, since the generated file is not included).

Comment: @Engelard It's not useless in a sense that this is there the generated classes for your UI live. So you can't remove it unless you also change the auto-generated files, that would be overridden on your next change. So I advise you not to. Besides, there is nothing wrong with the namespace and removing it wouldn't help anything, unless you hold some deep unexplainable grudge against namespaces.